# How to navigate to a new Screen when using SideBarController in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, sidebar

I have an application with a lot of screens, let say HomePage, Section Screen and Detail Page, Category Screen.

I use a NavigationController to Navigate from HomePage to Section Screen.

In the SectionScreen I have used a SideBarController component (https://components.xamarin.com/view/sidebarnavigation) to implement a navigation drawer or a flyout menu.

The problem is how to navigate from `Section Screen` to `Detail Page` or to `Category Screen`. I need to make this kind of navigation from `MenuController` or `ContentController`.

I don't want to just change the `contentView`. I want to push another `UIViewController`.

I have used the usual one:

```
this.NavigationController.PushViewController( new UIViewControllerExample(), true);
```

but there are some problems:

- In the details page I can't access the `NavigationBar`
- When I press `back`, the app crashes with an error:

  Cant add self to subview

This is how to it should look like.
[image]

This is the problem. The first image display what happen when i use the above code,

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

as you can find in that page of component you should use SidebarController as your navigationcontroller

```
  SidebarController.ChangeContentView(new OtherContentController());
```

Comment: Well I know that, but as I stated above I don't want to change the contentView, I need to navigate in a new screen.